# Time is shorter, but the fun will never end

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Come around, come around, glad you all came.
>   Welcome to the land where a small, hairy ball got its fame.
>   Here you can see a dysfunctional family.
>   A man who beat his wife and left his son voluntarily.
>   Here you can see the Devil himself.
>   Following a high school girl who showing off her wealth.
>   Here you can see a different world.
>   A hasty get up makes a teenage boy crippled.

What/Where am I describing?

Hint:

> The land is not real.

Hint 2:

> All you need is a little green to understand.

Comment: any hint? is it an object, place, person?

Comment: It's only been 5h, I will add a hint if the first answer is far off

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, one of my hint is off, here a addition clue if you want rot13(V jnf zvferzrzorerq orpnhfr gur jbeq jnf phg fubeg.). Sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an effort (don't really believe I got it):

> You are referring to the tv show "Lucifer"

Come around, come around, glad you all came.

> Just an invitation? Its wording is very Lucifer-like when he would ask the crowd something.

Welcome to the land where a small, hairy ball got its fame.

> Really stumped about this.

Here you can see a dysfunctional family.

> The doctor has commented on this being the most dysfunctional family

A man who beat his wife and left his son voluntarily.

> God "left" his son take comand of hell, and he "beat" his wife to go in there

Here you can see the Devil himself.

> Easy

Following a high school girl who showing off her wealth.

> Reference to Hot tub whatitwas where Chloe showed her "wealth"

Here you can see a different world.

> Indeed, haven't heard of a Lux club

A feline friend makes a teenage boy crippled.

> You could maybe comment Mazikeen's agility as being feline. I don't remember all the episodes, but she must have hit some teenage boy some time.

Title

> The seasons will always be few in comparison to how much we love it, but at least we can we watch it again and again.

Comment: good try. I will add a hint soon

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot at it, I guess you are describing

> the cartoon character *Doraemon*,

which, in some cases like

> ... different world, feline friend, dysfunctional family matches the description.

Though, this is a partial one.

Comment: Well I mean, rot13(V qba'g erzrzore Qbenrzba orra gung qnex) . good try though

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to venture a guess:

> Is it the land of **Ooo**, from *Adventure Time*? (Spoilers ahead for the show’s plot)

Come around, come around, glad you all came.

> The title song begins, “Adventure Time! Come on, grab your friends.”
>
>  The outro/credits song begins with, “Come along with me...”

Welcome to the land where a small, hairy ball got its fame.

> A reference to **Jake the Dog**. As well as gaining popularity as a main character, his *Bacon Pancakes* song is a memorable part of the show.

Here you can see a dysfunctional family.
A man who beat his wife and left his son voluntarily.

> Finn’s family could be described as dysfunctional. For one, his dad was basically a criminal in the society where Finn’s mother lived. Fast forward about ten or fifteen years and Finn’s dad is in various stages of imprisonment while his mom lives inside a computer an entire ocean away. His dad repeatedly abandons him, and his mom almost keeps Finn trapped on the island. Kinda messed up.
>
>  As for “beating” his wife...well, he really “beat” her initial expectations of him. He “beat it” when he had to leave. :-)
>
>   ...okay, I haven’t really figured out *that* part yet.

Here you can see the Devil himself.
Following a high school girl who showing off her wealth.

> We see **the Lich** (an absolutely evil embodiment of death and destruction) possess **Princess Bubblegum** after she “shows off her wealth” by giving Finn and Jake special gems.

Here you can see a different world.

> Ooo is still the Earth, but the mutagenic bomb changed everything.

A hasty get up makes a teenage boy crippled.

> The grass sword binds to Finn’s arm. When it is first lost, Finn loses his arm with it.

Title:

> “With Jake the Dog and Finn the Human, *the fun will never end,* it’s Adventure Time!”

Comment: Good try, but rot13(V'z abg whfg gnyxvat nobhg n pnegbba)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to

> The Addams Family

Come around, come around, glad you all came.

> The family is very welcoming to guests

Welcome to the land where a small, hairy ball got its fame.

> Cousin Itt isn't much more than a small, hairy ball

Here you can see a dysfunctional family.

> You can make the case that the Addams are dysfunctional, but they're mostly just weird

A man who beat his wife and left his son voluntarily.

> This one is a bit weak, Uncle Fester maybe, in the Addams Family movies?

Here you can see the Devil himself.
Following a high school girl who showing off her wealth.

> The Addams are wealthy, and Wednesday Addams has a pet lizard named Lucifer

Here you can see a different world.
A hasty get up makes a teenage boy crippled.

> This one I am also very unsure about